# ORA-040901 - Table is mutating,trigger/function PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I execute "MERGE" to be able to insert all those values ​​that don't match my MST_PRO table but originally it has a trigger that when entering a new record takes the last value generated to use the next ID in the table
But when executing this code in PLSQL it generates the following error:

```
ORA-04091: table SCHEMA.MST_PRO is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TGR_MST_PRO", LINE4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCHEMA.TGR_MST_PRO'
```

What should I change to be able to insert the records into the MST_PRO table?

```
merge into MST_PRO tm
using (select * from mst_pro_tmp) ts
on ( tm.P_NAME = ts.P_NAME)
when not matched then
 insert(tm.P_TEAM, tm.P_NUMB, tm.P_NAME, tm.P_REQ, tm.P_DATE, tm.P_TYPE)
 values(ts.P_TEAM, ts.P_NUMB, ts.P_NAME, ts.P_REQ, ts.P_DATE, 'EXP');
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TGR_MST_PRO
  before insert on mst_pro
  for each row WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
declare
  
begin
  SELECT NVL(MAX(ID),0) + 1 INTO :NEW.ID FROM MST_PRO;
end TGR_MST_PRO;
```

Comment: Does it help you at all to disable the trigger before you run your `merge`, and then reenable it?

Comment: Yes it helps but, need the trigger in order to save records from API

Comment: Pay attention to @Littlefoot's answer; sequences are the answer you're looking for. Also note that you got the mutating table error because you can't touch the table to which the trigger belongs from *within* the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you're doing it wrong. `max + 1` is a good way to worse problems than the ones you have now. As long as it works in a single-user environment, it'll miserably fail in multi-user one when two (or more) users run the same code, fetch the same `max` value, add `1` to it and either

- generate duplicates, or
- raise `dup_val_on_index` if `ID` is primary or unique key

The first user who commits will succeed - everyone else will produce error.

---

What to do? Switch to **sequence**.

```
create sequence seq;

create or replace trigger TGR_MST_PRO
  before insert on mst_pro
  for each row 
  when (new.id is null)
begin
  :new.id := seq.nextval;
end TGR_MST_PRO;
```

Now run `merge`.

---

If you happen to find information that - if you create trigger as autonomous transaction - it'll start working, sure - it will, but that'll just *hide* problems as you'll still have the same *duplicates* issue.

Another option is to create compound trigger (if your database version supports it), or (older approach) package with a variable that gets updated by row-level trigger and used by statement-level trigger.

Once again, don't do that. `max + 1` is simply *evil*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but create the sequence doesn't work for me

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Because the column is already have rows , I want to take the last ID and assign  to each record example: "Merge result return 9 rows" and need to insert each record using last value ID as 1: -"ID:50 ,data, data data, data, data, data " ,"  2.- ID:51 ,data, data data, data, data, data " ... 9 .- "ID: 58 ,data, data data, data, data, data " ETC

Comment: Aha; you're saying that ID already contains data. Is that right? If so, no problem. Find MAX ID value (suppose it is 3427), and then `create sequence seq start with 3428` so that you won't get duplicates. That should do.